Как запустить скомпилированный скрипт Python скрыто при передаче флага при запуске?
У меня есть консольная программа для рассылки которая скомпилирована в exe файл через PyInstaller.
При открытии она открывает консоль и выводит сведения о работе в неё, но я хочу добавить флаг "-s" при подаче которого программа будет открываться без отображения консоли. Подскажите как это можно реализовать в Python 3.11?

Всё оказалась не так уж и сложно.
Создаём обработчик аргументов, и к аргументу -s привязываем следующую функцию:
def Hide():
    import win32gui, win32con
    console = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
    win32gui.ShowWindow(console, win32con.SW_HIDE)

После её выполнения окно консоли будет мгновенно скрыто.
Для повторного отображения консоли используем функцию:
def Show():
    import win32gui, win32con
    console = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
    win32gui.ShowWindow(console, win32con.SW_SHOW)


Попробуйте
--hide-console hide-early


Есть ещё вариант:
import ctypes as ctypes

def show_console(mode=0): ctypes.windll.user32.ShowWindow(ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleWindow(), mode)

Если mode=0, консоль скрыта, если mode=3, консоль показана и максимизирована. Есть и другие варианты параметра для показа консоли, см. документацию.
Для того, чтоб попытаться вообще замаскировать, нужно привлекать при сборке опцию --hide-console hide-early. Однако, я не уверен, что это сильно поможет. Всё равно на экране что-то "дёрнется", особенно на слабых компах.
Надеюсь, понятно, что в моём варианте вы можете передавать свой флаг в такую функцию. Передавайте 0 или 3, но в этому случае не назначайте mode по умолчанию.

Кто-то мне недавно писал, что неудобно читать длинные строки (или широкий код?). Или вы только в свою пользу это применяете? Зачем все так лепить в одну строку, разделите нормально, чтобы все после двоеточия было на отдельной строке.

Это действительно проблема? Я предоставил своё решение. Что с ним будут делать и как его будут оформлять, мне не очень интересно. Неужели я должен реагировать на такие пустяки?  Мне именно так удобно использовать эту функцию! Потому что она библиотечная. Я один раз с ней поработал, а далее в библиотеке мне НЕ надо чтоб она занимала пол-экрана, если она вполне может занимать одну строку. Когда я бегаю по библиотеке, мне так удобнее и быстрее.
Есть и другое соображение, пусть и не столь важное. Однострочную функцию вполне себе можно использовать в виде лямбды.

Это действительно проблема, когда нужно по горизонтали крутить код. Да хоть 100 библиотченая, не нужно все одну строку лепить. Когда вы у себя в коде пишите и никому этот код не показываете - без проблем. Хоть весь модуль в одну строку пишите. Если вы где-то код выкладываете - ожидайте, что вам обязательно кто-то напишет про нормальные способы форматирования кода (в том числе про PEP8).

Да, я поклонник однострочников. Могу даже книжку порекомендовать - там обучают такому мастерству ("Однострочники Python". К.Майер). Мне тут курсы ударяния по клавише enter учредить? Извините, но у меня есть более продуктивные занятия.
